# How to give a compute engine VM permission only to delete itself?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

My VM deletes itself after a given time using this code:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=\`curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" | python -c "import sys; import json; sys.stdout.write(json.loads(sys.stdin.read())['access_token'])"\`
                        
curl -X "DELETE" https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${gcp.project_id}/zones/${zone}/instances/${name} \\
-H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

The VM runs user supplied code; I want to lock down the VM so it can only delete itself.

I have created a role (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles) for `compute.instances.delete`, assigned it to a new service account, and assigned the service account to the VM.

The issue is that it only seems to work when created with these scopes which provide too much access to the Google APIs:

```
            serviceAccounts: [
                {
                    email: "service account email with just delete role",
                    scopes: [
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute"
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Without the above scopes I get `"No service account scopes specified."` in the ACCESS_TOKEN response.

Can this be done?

Comment: Go to the Google Cloud Console. Select the VM. In the right-side panel, you can grant an IAM identity (user, service account, etc) IAM roles to only that instance. Remove the IAM role for that user from the Project IAM. Now the user only has permissions to a single VM instance. Note: the scope **compute** is part of **cloud-platform**. Do not specify both, just **cloud-platform**.

Comment: @JohnHanley These are being created via the Node API. How would I give the VM only the `compute.instances.delete` role? What needs to go into the `scopes`  array?

Comment: What is being created via the Node API? For Google IAM, scopes limit permissions that are already granted. Scopes do not grant permissions. Use the scope **cloud-platform** and manage IAM role bindings at the project or resource.

Comment: **According to GCP public documentation:**
_The authorization provided to applications hosted on a Compute Engine instance is limited by two separate configurations: the roles granted to the attached service account, and the access scopes that you set on the instance. Both of these configurations must allow access before the application running on the instance can access a resource.
The best practice is to set the full cloud-platform access scope on the instance, then control the service account's access using IAM roles._

Comment: Why do you believe that cloud-platform scope will provide too much access to your Google APIs?

Comment: @IsmaelClementeAguirre Isn't https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform full access? User code is run on this VM so I do not want them calling the HTTP API for GCP to read/write cloud resources.

Comment: The scope **cloud-platform** does not grant full access. Access permissions are controlled by IAM roles. Please reread my previous comment.